# Эффективная работа с большими объемами данных

Tags: алгоритм, big-data

Изначальная архитектура приложения была построена ошибочно - все данные сливались в один файл, размер которого перевалил теперь за отметку 950ГБ.

Есть ли какой-нибудь эффективный метод (из области big-data) выделения из этого массива данных групп сущностей, состоящих из одних и тех же символов (так называемых анаграмм)?

Comment: Кроме индексации + кэширования ничего умного еще не придумали.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вы умеете при последовательном чтении выделять сущности и хотели бы построить индекс для их анаграмм? Каково предполагаемое количество анаграмм и средний размер сущности?

Comment: И еще. Какими техническими средствами располагаете? Думаю,  алгоритмы для кластера из сотни узлов, связанными infiniband и устройствами хранения со страйпингом по десятку SSD дисков и несколькими PC в локалке с терабайтными HDD могут существенно отличаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартная идея вот какая:

1. К каждой сущности дописать её номер в исходном списке.
2. У каждой сущности отсортировать символы.
3. Отсортировать сущности. Теперь анаграммы будут находиться рядом.
4. Теперь для нахождения анаграмм нужен лишь один пробег по данным.

Все эти операции хорошо «параллелятся», Кроме, пожалуй сортировки.

С учётом этого можно изменить немного алгоритм:

1. Распартиционировать данные как угодно.
2. Пронумеровать сущности и отсортировать их символы на каждом хосте по отдельности (номеру назначать уникальный префикс, чтобы не смешивать)
3. Отсортировать данные каждого хоста.
4. Смёржить все данные. Сначала заливать результат на первый хост, когда `1/n` всех данных зальётся — на второй хост и т. д. (Это по сути перепартиционирование.)
5. Далее пробег по данным на каждом хосте.

Вместо пункта 4, возможно, более эффективно будет не сливать данные вместе, а делать многохостовый пробег:

```
string currentValue = null;
int anagramCount = 0;
string[] nextByHost = new string[N];
for (i = 0..n-1) { currentByHost[i] = ""; nextByHost = fetch from host[i]; }

while (any of hosts has data)
{
    if any of nextByHost[i] equals to currentValue,
        anagramCount++
        fetch next from host[i] to nextByHost[i]
    else
        store currentValue and anagramCount
        currentValue = min(nextByHost)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но этот алгоритм будет достаточно прожорливым. Если, скажем, имеется ~ 50 млрд сущностей...сортировка накроется, если нет достаточного количества памяти =(

Comment: @0xFFh: Окей, сейчас допишу. Обойдёмся сортировкой на хостах.

Comment: @0xFFh: Добавил ещё вариант.

Comment: Хм, интересно. Осталось более детально разобраться. Благодарю)

Comment: @0xFFh: не за что!

Comment: Не очень представляю сортировку терабайта данных.

Comment: @avp: В алгоритме нету сортировки терабайта. Там лишь внутренняя сортировка на хостах. Добавьте больше хостов — будет сортировка меньшего количества данных :)

Comment: А мерджить их Вы как собираетесь? Это же все равно заключительная фаза многопутевой сортировки слиянием. Кстати, результат работы алгоритма я толком не понял.

Comment: @avp: Так и есть, я пытался на коленке её описать. Результат алгоритма — набор из наборов id строк, сгруппированные по одинаковым отсортированным строкам. То есть если в начале было `dog`, `cat`, `god`, после партиционирования и сортировки выйдет `{ dgo, 1 }`, `{ act, 2 }`, `{ act, 3}`, а после слияния — кортеж набор кортежей (в нашем случае из одного кортежа `[2, 3]`).

Comment: @avp, насчет сортировки терабайта. Здесь действительно возникла проблема: либо память, либо время. Но, тем не менее, если иметь ввиду многопоточность производимой операции, то время удастся значительно сократить.  + Мерджи придется реализовывать с несколько иной логикой.

Comment: Почему `[2, 3]`, а не, скажем, `[1, 2]` все равно не понял. Неважно. Суть в том, что получаем множество id анаграмм? Так? И что с ними дальше делать?

Comment: @0xFFh, Вы лучше про доступные средства и что думаете с выделенными группами дальше делать напишите.

Comment: @avp: `[2, 3]` потому, что `act (id 2) == act (id 3)`. А дальше имея id, возвращаемся к исходным данным, и по id находим `cat` и `act`.

Comment: Ага, т.е. в начальном комментарии очепятка не в том месте, о котором я подумал -- вместо `god` надо читать  `act` (та же анаграмма, что и у `cat`). А кортеж из одного элемента для `dog` Вы просто не рассматриваете? / Вообще-то мне кажется, что вместо анаграмм можно сразу перейти к их хэшам (например 64-бит murmur или что-то вроде) и заносить в базу только их вместе с id сущности (на самом деле м.б. вместе со смещением сущности в исходном файле. Впрочем, это я уже фантазирую, не зная, чего на самом деле хочет ТС).

Comment: @avp: А, тьфу, точно. Опечатка. Ну, одноэлементный кортеж для ТС вроде бы не нужен — раз. Ну и я надеюсь, что анаграмм будет не так много, и тогда без одноэлементных кортежей будет не такой огромный результат.